# Unable to load properties with Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am a complete newbie to Spring. I am trying to figure out how to access properties from props files injected into my app through Spring.

I wrote a simple test provided below. I run it by passing location of the properties file through environment variables provided at JRE options

```
$ mvn test -DSPRING_CONFIG_NAME=my_spring \
  -DSPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:///Users/desilets/Documents/conf
```

Here is the content of the my_spring.properties file

```
$ cat /Users/desilets/Documents/conf/my_spring.properties 
my.spring.greeting=hello world
```

When I run the test, it fails. Yet the output indicates that the environment variables were well received:

```
SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=my_spring
SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:///Users/desilets/Documents/conf
greeting=null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thx.

---- Code for the test ---

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class AccessPropertiesTest {
    
    @Value("${my.spring.greeting}")
    String greeting;

    @Test
    public void test__LoadProperties() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SPRING_CONFIG_NAME="+
            System.getProperty("SPRING_CONFIG_NAME"));
        System.out.println("SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION="+
            System.getProperty("SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION"));
        System.out.println("greeting="+greeting);
        Assert.assertEquals(
            "The property my.spring.greeting was not read correctly", 
            greeting, "hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

If its a spring project there would be two locations for properties

src/main/resources

src/test/resources

If you run tests it will pick from src/test/resources.

Comment: Thx for the response. Unfortunately, this won't do as I want to use a properties file that is EXTERNAL to the project's resources.

Comment: Did you also try --spring.config.location=<FILE_LOCATION>

Comment: --spring.config.location is a command line argument that is supported by Spring apps only. If I try mvn test --spring.config.location, it says it's an invalid option.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class AccessPropertiesTest {
    @Value("${my.spring.greeting}")
    String greeting;
    .....
}
```

refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing
add: my.spring.greeting=anyValue into application.properties or application.properties.yaml file

Comment: Thx for the reply. It sounds like the recipe you describe requires me to put the config in application.properties inside my project. But I want to use a props file that resides OUTSIDE the project.